# phonegap: how to store recorded audio by media plugin in app folder?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, audio, phonegap-build

How to store recorded audio to the app folder?

I am using cordova's media plugin to record audio in android and ios.

I want to store recorded voice into the app folder ( e.g. com.appname.www ) so that all recorded files can be removed automatically on uninstall.

I want standard solution for both android and ios. 
Following is the code I am using:

```
var my_media = new Media('my_recording.wav');
my_media.startRecord();
// after few seconds..
my_media.stopRecord();
my_media.play(); // works fine
```

I want to move my_recording.wav into my app's folder like WHATS APP
The purpose to have have all recordings in a folder so that those recordings can be removed automatically upnon unintall.

Comment: I bet you do. I love standard solutions too. Wrong place to ask though if you don't want to put any effort into it yourself.

Comment: I already put effort on it. But I am unable to find right solution.

Comment: The problem is that we don't see it here. If you want us to invest our time answering your question, you should show us what you tried at the very least. At the moment, this looks like a request to design and write a project for you for free, and that is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I updated my question and tried to add more details in it. I hope it's better than before. I just want right direction as I am new into this.